# Close window (stage) when the service has finished the task (JavaFx)

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task, progress-bar

I opened a windows with a progressIndicator from a controller because i needed to launch a long task.
The windows is generated by a FXML loader with this code:

```
[...]
public void showProgressBar() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("progress-view.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Caricamento");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
[...]
```

After that i created a service that launch a task:

Task:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class GetTemperatureListTask extends Task<ObservableList<Temperature>> {
@Override
protected ObservableList<Temperature> call() throws Exception {
    updateProgress(0,100);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    updateProgress(50,100);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    updateProgress(100,100);
    Thread.sleep(500);

    ObservableList<Temperature> tempList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    tempList.add(new Temperature(10.0,"ciao"));
    tempList.add(new Temperature(20.0,"ciao"));

    return tempList;
          }
    }
```

Service:

```
package com.example.temperature.DataSource;

import com.example.temperature.domain.Temperature;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class GetTemperatureListService extends Service<ObservableList<Temperature>> {
@Override
protected Task<ObservableList<Temperature>> createTask() {
    return new GetTemperatureListTask();
   }
}
```

And from Controller I called the service with the task and binded them with progresIndicator:

```
package com.example.temperature.controller;

import com.example.temperature.DataSource.GetTemperatureListService;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class ProgressController {
@FXML
private AnchorPane apPane;
@FXML
private ProgressIndicator piProgress;
public void initialize() {
    createProgress();
}
@FXML
public void createProgress(){
    GetTemperatureListService service = new GetTemperatureListService();
    piProgress.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
    service.start();

    
    }
   }
```

How can I close the windwos after completed task?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a listener to the progressIndicator and inside the lambda function close the windows getted by the pane

```
package com.example.temperature.controller;

import com.example.temperature.DataSource.GetTemperatureListService;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class ProgressController {
@FXML
private AnchorPane apPane;
@FXML
private ProgressIndicator piProgress;
public void initialize() {
    createProgress();
}
@FXML
public void createProgress(){
    GetTemperatureListService service = new GetTemperatureListService();
    piProgress.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
    service.start();

    service.setOnSucceeded((event)->{
        piProgress.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not use `service.setOnSucceeded`?

Comment: This approach will probably work as long as the progress actually gets to 1.0 before the Task ends.  But maybe it only gets to 0.999.  Maybe not bother with Service, just manually create a Task and pass the Stage to it and then close it on Task.setOnSucceeded().

Comment: It is mutch better, thanks
SedJ601